# stop superagent after receiving first byte (to only get redirect url)

Tags: node.js, http, superagent

I'm using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) (although willing to user other node lib) with the goal to solely get the redirected url, but not the body. The latter is overkill and I want to prevent my code to download the body if I can help it.

I cannot use `HEAD` requests since these are not guaranteed to be enabled on the server.

Instead my idea was to pipe the superagent response to a writeStream and stop the writeStream on receiving the first data. However, `.on('data', fn)` is only available on a readstream instead of a writestream.

Instead I tried to see if `superagent.get(...)` itself was a readstream on which I could listen for `.on('data', fn)` to kill the stream, but that doesn't appear to be the case either.

In short, is there another way to cancel a request early, while still getting the redirect url, but not incurring the download overhead of the entire body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: needed `buffer(false)`. Using that response can be treated as a proper readstream.

```
            const url = "http://www.google.com";
            superagent.get(url)
            .buffer(false)
            .end(function (err, res) {
              const urlRedirect = res.redirects.length ? res.redirects.pop() : url;
              res.destroy();
              res.on("end", function () {
                //do stuff with 'urlRedirect'
              })
            })
```